# How to switch databases while browsing a database

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4j database open in a browser window. Is there a cypher command to stop the current database and start a different database without leaving the browser?

I can do it this way but it's inconvenient:

[image: How to switch databases]

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the cypher query at this time to restart or change the database.